# Can chrome complete clone an opened page?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

During web coding, We will check the page quite often. To accelerate our speed, We will open two page, one for change, one for compare.

Is there a way to clone an page completely? I mean not the usual way that open current page's URL in an new tab. I wish that eg. if Page A open a tab via js and load data via ajax, then the clone Page B should open tabe and load data too.

If can, it will be totally amazing. Thanks.

Comment: You can check a [`duplicate`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-duplicate) method of chrome extension API, but probably it not exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can use [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) api of javascript

Comment: How? Can you describe it in detail? Thank you very much.

Comment: You can look into an example here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob#Examples

Comment: I still don't see the relationship between Blob and my question. How can a blob help during clone a same opened page? @Deepak

Comment: //Run this code in your page
var blob = new Blob([$('html').html()], {type: 'text/html'}); // pass a useful mime type here
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
window.open(url)

Comment: Oh My God! It works, thank you for what a amazing idea! One more thing, if the source of html is relative, should replace it with absolute. Otherwise, css or script will not load right. @ Deepak